# goog.inherits present in the output file

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I'm trying to use Closure Compiler and Closure Library.

When I use the library everything is ok, I'm including "base.js" in my simulation and it works with all my javascript files.

The problem is present when I "compilate" my application: In the output file I've got a reference to a closure library'sfunction "**goog.inherits**".

From what I've read, it's not necessary to include "base.js" in production. I'm working on a library, so I don't want to force users to have a reference to the Closure Library.

How can I do?

Here is my code:

```
NM.ObjectEvent = function( type )
{
    goog.base(this);
}
goog.inherits( NM.ObjectEvent, NM.Event );
```

And the script look like that:

```
java -jar compiler.jar  --compilation_level SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS --js_output_file myLib.js `find ../src/ -name '*.js'`
```

Comment: The compiler outputs one big file that has everything you need (e.g. all the functions in base.js, unless the compiler determines that some are unused) so you should be able to just serve myLib.js itself.

Answer (score 1):

What you have heard does not apply to SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS.  With ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS everything unused in base.js is removed, with SIMPLE_OPTIMIZATIONS only function local optimizations are performed and unused methods are not removed.

Regardless of the mode, if you use goog.inherits it will remain in some form.  Something needs to do the work that goog.inherits does to setup the prototype chain.

Answer (score 0):

Like John said, if you have references to `goog.base` and `goog.inherits`, you're referencing the library.  Fortunately, you can emulate those functions...  Something like this should work...

```
NM.ObjectEvent = function( type )
{
    NM.Event.call(this, type);
}
(function(){
  var temp = function(){};
  temp.prototype = NM.Event.prototype;
  NM.ObjectEvent.prototype = new temp();
}();
```

If you're using `goog.base` elsewhere (for example, to call superclass methods), then you'll need to do more work, but the above should suffice if you're only using `base` and `inherits` where shown in your original post.